# Solve the equation $\left | \tan x \right | = 2 \cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation

$\left | \tan x \right | = 2 \cos^2x$

Comment: What happens if $x=\pi/4$,$x=3\pi/4$,$x=5\pi/4$,$x=(2k+1)\pi/4$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, How have you identified them ?

Comment: I really don't know ! It immediately came to my mind because of the rhs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking squares, $$\tan^2x=4\cos^4x$$

Setting $\sec^2x=a, a^2(a-1)=4\iff a^3-a^2-4=0$

Clearly $a=2$ is a solution, $\implies \sec^22x=2\implies\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=0\implies2x=(2n+1)\frac\pi2$